# Tensorflow doesn't work with gpu - too much memory is used. How to solve it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I use tensorflow for image classification (20 classes) with convolutions. My dataset contains about 20000 train images and 5000 test images. Images (RGB) have 200x256 pixels. When I run script to train model using cpu everything seems fine. However when I try run script using gpu, after loading my training and test data I get error on model_fit function.

```
Num GPUs Available:  1
2022-05-04 17:58:58.482057: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-05-04 17:59:03.655618: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4634 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060, pci bus id: xxxx:xx:xx.x, compute capability: 6.1
1 Physical GPUs, 1 Logical GPUs
Path: D:/Dataset/seg_train
Loading seg_train
Path: D:/Dataset/seg_test
Loading seg_test
2022-05-04 18:02:48.971100: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:462] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 10.44GiB (rounded to 11206656000)requested by op _EagerConst
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation.
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.996013: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1010] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
2022-05-04 18:02:48.996173: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (256):  Total Chunks: 16, Chunks in use: 16. 4.0KiB allocated for chunks. 4.0KiB in use in bin. 392B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.996308: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (512):  Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 512B allocated for chunks. 512B in use in bin. 512B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.996473: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (1024):         Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 1.2KiB allocated for chunks. 1.2KiB in use in bin. 1.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.996629: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (2048):         Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 1. 7.0KiB allocated for chunks. 3.5KiB in use in bin. 3.4KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.996889: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (4096):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.997493: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (8192):         Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 9.5KiB allocated for chunks. 9.5KiB in use in bin. 9.5KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.997960: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (16384):        Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 19.0KiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.998482: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (32768):        Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 1. 79.5KiB allocated for chunks. 36.0KiB in use in bin. 36.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.999113: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (65536):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:48.999710: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (131072):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.000273: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (262144):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.000742: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (524288):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.001208: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (1048576):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.001671: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (2097152):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.002131: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (4194304):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.002700: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (8388608):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.004034: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (16777216):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.004682: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (33554432):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 44.56MiB allocated for chunks. 44.56MiB in use in bin. 44.56MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.005383: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (67108864):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 89.12MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.007520: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (134217728):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.008016: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (268435456):    Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 4.39GiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-04 18:02:49.008477: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1033] Bin for 10.44GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State:
2022-05-04 18:02:49.008888: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1039]   Size: 4.39GiB | Requested Size: 0B | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 44.56MiB | Requested Size: 44.56MiB | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2022-05-04 18:02:49.009335: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Next region of size 4859428864
2022-05-04 18:02:49.025604: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00000 of size 256 next 1
2022-05-04 18:02:49.025772: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00100 of size 1280 next 2
2022-05-04 18:02:49.026373: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00600 of size 256 next 3
2022-05-04 18:02:49.026991: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00700 of size 256 next 4
2022-05-04 18:02:49.028407: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00800 of size 256 next 5
2022-05-04 18:02:49.028560: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00900 of size 256 next 6
2022-05-04 18:02:49.029196: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00a00 of size 256 next 9
2022-05-04 18:02:49.029937: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00b00 of size 256 next 10
2022-05-04 18:02:49.030556: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00c00 of size 256 next 11
2022-05-04 18:02:49.031054: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00d00 of size 256 next 14
2022-05-04 18:02:49.031553: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00e00 of size 256 next 15
2022-05-04 18:02:49.031906: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a00f00 of size 512 next 16
2022-05-04 18:02:49.032334: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a01100 of size 256 next 19
2022-05-04 18:02:49.032719: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a01200 of size 256 next 20
2022-05-04 18:02:49.033158: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a01300 of size 256 next 21
2022-05-04 18:02:49.033523: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a01400 of size 256 next 24
2022-05-04 18:02:49.033892: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a01500 of size 256 next 25
2022-05-04 18:02:49.034323: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a01600 of size 256 next 26
2022-05-04 18:02:49.034824: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] Free  at b03a01700 of size 3584 next 7
2022-05-04 18:02:49.035472: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a02500 of size 3584 next 8
2022-05-04 18:02:49.035923: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] Free  at b03a03300 of size 19456 next 23
2022-05-04 18:02:49.036957: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a07f00 of size 9728 next 22
2022-05-04 18:02:49.039251: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] Free  at b03a0a500 of size 44544 next 13
2022-05-04 18:02:49.039789: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b03a15300 of size 36864 next 12
2022-05-04 18:02:49.040234: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] Free  at b03a1e300 of size 93454336 next 18
2022-05-04 18:02:49.040779: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at b0933e300 of size 46727168 next 17
2022-05-04 18:02:49.041233: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] Free  at b0bfce300 of size 4719123712 next 18446744073709551615
2022-05-04 18:02:49.041719: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1071]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size:
2022-05-04 18:02:49.042440: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 16 Chunks of size 256 totalling 4.0KiB
2022-05-04 18:02:49.042831: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 512 totalling 512B
2022-05-04 18:02:49.043889: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
2022-05-04 18:02:49.044474: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 3584 totalling 3.5KiB
2022-05-04 18:02:49.044901: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 9728 totalling 9.5KiB
2022-05-04 18:02:49.045330: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 36864 totalling 36.0KiB
2022-05-04 18:02:49.045784: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 46727168 totalling 44.56MiB
2022-05-04 18:02:49.046196: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1078] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 44.62MiB
2022-05-04 18:02:49.046552: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1080] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 4859428864 memory_limit_: 4859428864 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 9718857728
2022-05-04 18:02:49.046902: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1086] Stats:
Limit:                      4859428864
InUse:                        46783232
MaxInUse:                    140225792
NumAllocs:                          34
MaxAllocSize:                 46727168
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2022-05-04 18:02:49.047317: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:474] ***_________________________________________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DatasetProcessing\ImageClassification.py", line 394, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\DatasetProcessing\ImageClassification.py", line 387, in main
    first_model()
  File "D:\DatasetProcessing\ImageClassification.py", line 162, in first_model
    history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=2, epochs=4)
  File "D:\WinPython\WPy64-3980\python-3.9.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "D:\WinPython\WPy64-3980\python-3.9.8.amd64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

I have a notebook with nvidia gtx 1060 (6GB) gpu. I've installed the newest driver available for this gpu and cuda version 11.2. I checked gpu values in task manager when script was running but it was 1% up to 5%. It looks like tensorflow is not using gpu at all.

I tried to use:

```
TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async
```

and

```
memory_limit=4096
```

and

```
allow_growth=True
```

I've also decreased `batch_size` from 128 to 2. But neither of these options worked.

Model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (200, 256, 3)),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation = tf.nn.softmax)
        ])
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=2, epochs=4)
```

It's a simple model, but I get error on model_fit function.

Comment: The title is misleading, TensorFlow IS working with the GPU, you are just using too much memory, and you did not describe your model or how the memory is being allocated.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Hi, i've edited title, to specify my problem. My model has 2 Conv2d layers with 32 filters and 2 maxpooling layers. Next is Flatten layer and then 2 Dense layers. What do you mean by "how the memory is being allocated"? I'm new to tensorflow

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy 'ive tried memory_limit and allow_growth=True for memory allocation

Comment: Maybe just include your code in the question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I added code in the question. I don't know if it helps to determine the problem and solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have a lstm model for binary classificartion
and I run it on GCP with 2 GPU.
As I had this problem for few days now, tried all of this at the beginning:

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for device in gpu_devices:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)
```

and this:

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

Also this:

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

Nothing worked and finally found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth):
Basically what it does is, it copied your model on both GPU so that it will run a copy of your model on each GPU, splitting the input data between them, also known as "data parallelism".

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(gpus)
with strategy.scope():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(layer_unit, input_shape=(lookback,number_of_feature ),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(dr))
    for i in range(hidden_layer_no-2):
        model.add(LSTM(layer_unit,return_sequences=True))
        model.add(Dropout(dr))
    model.add(LSTM(layer_unit))
    model.add(Dropout(dr))

    model.add(Dense(forward,activation='sigmoid')) # relu
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
```

Disclaimer: I do not know if it work on 1 GPU